# swift 2 UITableViewController

Tags: swift, tableview

I am new to swift. I am trying to create an app using table view controller.
Here is my code. The output is not displayed. print works fine outside.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
let url :String = "https://testurl.com"
var arr:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


class AlertTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    arr = (response.result.value) as! NSMutableArray

                    print("JSON: \(json)")
                    print (arr.count)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arr.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AlertTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlertTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        //cell.Label1.text = json["ALERTID"].stringValue
      //  cell.Labl1.text=json[0]["ALERTID"].stringValue

        let dict = arr[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        print("dict")

        print(dict["ALERTID"])
        //cell.Label1.text  = String (dict["ALERTID"]! )

        cell.Label1.text = "Hello"
        cell.Label2.text = String (dict["PERSID"]! )
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your JSON response.

Comment: The classic: The Alamofire request works asynchronously. Put the code to reload the table view **in** the completion handler. PS: Use Swift `Array` rather than `NSMutableArray`. It makes things much easier. And declare the data source array `arr` **in** the class. And last but not least: I doubt that a cast to `NSMutableArray` works at all.

Comment: TableView Controller works same as tableView.Just Check array is nil?

Comment: Please add tableview in Loop.you are reloading tableview outside of Method

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your reloadTable inside the Almofire closure. Something as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                arr = (response.result.value) as! NSMutableArray

                print("JSON: \(json)")
                print (arr.count)
                //This is what i changed
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                  self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```